# How to show hidden files and folders in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos

I have a folder that starts with a dot `.` but am unable to display it in Finder.
How can I say that for folder *x*, Finder should also display hidden files/folders?

Comment: I'll just plug that Lion works the same as Snow Leopard with the hidden preference AppleShowAllFiles and Finder.

Comment: As of macOS 10.12,  Finder supports ⇧⌘. to toggle visibility of hidden files.

Comment: I have not yet found a solution that shows dotfiles by default in "open file" Finder dialogs spawned by other apps

Comment: @Plato `defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true` will show dotfiles in "open file dialogs" permanently. See [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99213/is-it-possible-to-always-show-hidden-dotfiles-in-open-save-dialogs/99214#99214)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I don't think you can set this for individual folders. To set it globally, so that Finder always shows hidden files, run Terminal and enter the following two commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true
killall Finder
```

To switch back, do the same but substitute `false` for `true`.

This works all the way through macOS Catalina (and betas for Big Sur).

Comment: This still works up to El Capitan - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal/258741#258741 for an Automator/hot key method.

Comment: Link to the best answer from the above linked question (the accepted answer is not the one you want). **TLDR:** you want to use the keyboard shortcut `shift + cmd + period` to make the finder show/hide these files. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264473/47407

Comment: This method doesnt seem to work in 10.13.5. At least its not showing any files starting with dot in the finder.

Comment: Worked for me now in 10.14.1

Comment: thank you @SunilD. Using the shift + cmd + period is much better than changing defaults permanently. Most times I don't need to see the hidden .git and .idea and other hidden files. I wish your comment was the accepted answer. I'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 and it works great

Comment: gtg in catalina

Answer (score 58):

In the Finder, press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files & folders.

Answer (score 12):

I myself use [hiddenfiles](https://github.com/Deminem/Hidden-Files) widget. it's so easy to use.

[image]

Beside that you can use free 3rd-party software like [Deeper](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23001/deeper) or [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another +1 for the Hidden Files widget. Quick and easy.

Comment: At the time of writing the download link for the Hidden Files widget is broken.

Comment: @saw-lau I test the link at it's fine now.

Comment: Links to hiddenFiles/Deeper/TinkerTool are broken and landing page has no information about them.

Comment: @vabhatia I fixed the link

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - Deeper link is still only to AppStore the others are OK

Answer (score 4):

You can customize Finder through Terminal commands such that it defaults to show/hide hidden files.

To show hidden files and restart Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

To hide hidden files and restart Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

s