# Enter a filename in the File Open dialog

Tags: macos

Can I enter a path to a file and its name instead of selecting a file in Mac OS X file dialog?

I tried just typing into an open dialog but it will just try to "Go to a folder", it won't accept a full path.

I'm on Mac OS X Lion

Comment: what about of https://www.macworld.com/article/1161022/copy-paste-file-paths.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Since it looks like you're just trying to open a hidden file, in the open dialog press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and the hidden files will appear.

[image: Open dialog]

Comment: thank you. but actually, I'm just looking for a way to minimize my mouse usage. and I hate selecting files like that

Comment: Once the hidden files are visible, you can type the filename and it will be selected. Alternatively, I suggest a third-party app like LaunchBar.

Comment: Once the hidden files are visible, you should be able to type-to-select.

Comment: wow, that worked! any chance to have hidden files shown by default? and maybe a tab-completion on the filepath?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder for showing hidden files by default.

Comment: I'll second LaunchBar. I use that to get to *everything* on my Mac.

Comment: Ian, but can I use it to replace the "Open File" dialog in applications? I want to open random files smoothly from Sublime Text

Comment: @valya it won't replace the open dialog, but you can use it to send files to Sublime Text. When I want to open a file I hit Cmd-Space to bring up LaunchPad, find the file and hit TAB and then I send it to the program and there it is. It's awesome.

Comment: Well that's interesting, but id doesn't actually answer the question as given...

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 177):

Yes. When the Finder dialog box is active type <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the `Go to the folder` direct entry dialog. You can enter the path to the file in the dialog using the Unix-type path expressions you'd expect: `~` for your home directory, `/` for a directory separator, etc.

[image: The Go To File dialog box]

Comment: hi. It's 'go to the folder', and it won't work for files (I'm trying on `~/.profile`)

Comment: You can also press "/" or "~" to enter the "Go to the folder:" drop-down, starting the path with "/" or "~" respectively.

Comment: @valya that sucks. I didn't realize it wouldn't let you enter the exact file in the dialog (I don't use it very often myself). Hopefully someone has a better answer.

Comment: no, sorry, Ian, you actually were right - take a look at comments to the different answer

Comment: Cmd+V not working on "Go to the folder" when copy from webstorm.. grr

Comment: Cmd+V is not working. But, right click -> Paste is working.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The answer now marked as accepted is an answer to a totally different question. Why does it have so many up votes?? Also, the `hidden-files` tag in the question is wrong as OP clearly states in a comment that the question is _not_ about finding hidden files.

Comment: Thanks! Why does it have to be so cryptic ?

Comment: "I'm so glad this basic necessity is abstracted away from the UI" said no one. Ever.

Answer (score 2):

The really nice thing about the "Go to folder" dialog is that auto-completion works - type the first couple of characters in the name, then TAB, and it fills in the rest of the characters.  If you get an error instead (say, you forgot one directory name in the path) you can correct it immediately instead of having to find the mistake at the end.  The only significant limitation is that you have to type an absolute path, starting at either your home directory or the file system root.  There's no concept of a current directory, as in bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a "Utilities > Terminal"
Then "open foo.txt" or "open fooApp.app"

"open" also works with folders in finder.

i aliased xdg-open to "open" on my linux boxes for this reason.

If it's a particular file type requiring special app (e.g.: not text) set the association in finder.