# How can I find and edit my external hard-drive's .fseventsd folder?

Tags: hard-drive

While changing my 'file directory' preferences on Vuze, I accidentally created a folder in the .fseventsd-folder on my Seagate external hard-drive.

I can't even find the .fseventsd-folder using search Spotlight, in fact the only way I can see this folder is when I go back to the file directory preferences from Vuze and I can't edit anything from there.

1. Is this going to damage anything, delete my data or anything weird like that?
2. Is there any way of deleting this folder (the accidentally created folder not the .fseventsd-folder)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show hidden files and folders in finder?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder)

Answer (score 1):

Files and folders starting with a '.' are invisible in Finder by default. You have [to activate this option](http://guides.macrumors.com/Viewing_hidden_files_on_a_Mac) in order to view/delete them.

Open Terminal and typ `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true`, after that, restart your Finder.
To hide those files again, open Terminal and type `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false` and restart Finder again.

But remember, they are hidden for a reason, so don't mess around with this kind of folders unless you are absolutely certain of your actions...

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with a terminal then navigate to your external disk (usually lives in the `/Volumes/` directory:

```
cd /Volumes/<Name-of-disk>/path/to/.fseventsd-folder
```

If you're not sure where this is you can find it by navigating to `/Volumes/<Name-of-disk>` and executing:

```
find . -name .fseventsd-folder
```

---

Once you are inside the directory, list the files in that directory (the `-a` lists hidden files—the ones that start with a `.`):

```
ls -a
```

Locate the name of the folder you accidentally created from the output of the above command and then use the following command:

```
rm -r -i <name-of-folder>
```

(The `-i` is optional but it will ask you to confirm the action if you're a little nervous.

---

Then exit the terminal using:

```
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show hidden files in Finder (files/folders starting with a "."), then another way how to gain access to a hidden folder is this:

- Open a Finder window
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- In the input dialog, type out the folder you want to get to.
  E.g. `/Volumes/250GB HDD/.fseventsd`...

*Note: You can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to **auto-complete**. For example, enter **`/Vo`** then Tab, and it will auto-complete to `/Volumes/`*