# Can't find file saved in Propellerhead Reason 8

Tags: terminal, finder, macbook-pro

I made a song in Propellerhead Reason 8 and I named the file ".cubicle..reason" but now I can't find the file. I was wondering how I could use terminal to locate the aforementioned file.

Answer (score 3):

Files that begin in a `.` are invisible to Finder. If you go to the directory in terminal and enter `ls -a` it will show the invisible files.

You can do `mv .cubicle..reason cubicle..reason` which will change the name and make the file visible.

To view hidden files in Finder see: [How to show hidden files and folders in finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder)