# Show ALL files starting with a dot in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

[This answer from 2011](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5871/150109) doesn't work for me:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true
killall Finder
```

I still can't see `.DS_Store` for example, `.localized`, `._.` etc

cmd shift <kbd>.</kbd> also doesn't work.

I can see other dotfiles after I use cmd shift <kbd>.</kbd>, just not `._.*`, `.DS_Store`, `.localized` so far.

Comment: Some _dot files_, e.g. `.DS_Store`, you can see in **Terminal** using e.g. `ls -a` however the ones you used to see in **Finder** and cannot now see them is because **Finder** is programmed to not show those files files even with it's set to show _hidden files_. The `._*` and `._.*` are  _extended attributes/resource fork files_ and normally cannot be seen in **Terminal** or **Finder** when properly associated/linked to their _normal files_ or if created on a _filesystem_ which does support them and either viewed from **Finder** or brought back to an **HFS+/APFS** _filesystem_.

Comment: CMD SHIFT . works for me on Catalina 10.15.7 You need to hold down all 3 keys to toggle between viewing and hiding hidden files. What is your experience?

Comment: Create a (temporary) user account. Log in and try the COMMAND-SHIFT-[PERIOD]. If it works then you have something installed that is hijacking or preventing that option. If it STILL doesn't work, try a Safe Boot. If that doesn't work then you may have an issue with your install of macOS

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the technical insight. I've asked a new question based on this https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410076/150109

Answer (score 4):

Finder supports<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to toggle hidden files. This is the same as using the `defaults write` command you list.

As of a recent version of macOS, this **does not** show `.DS_Store`, and there is no way to show `.DS_Store` files in Finder. There are likely other files that have the same exceptions applied to them. To view these files, use the terminal:

`ls -a`

Files that do not appear with `ls -a` either don't exist or cannot be viewed regardless of configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know about showing files starting with "." in the finder, but you can just as easily do what you want in the terminal. Just open the terminal go to the directory you want ( you start from your home directory you can use the "cd" command followed by the directory name like this: `cd desktop` or `cd download`. Once you are in the desired directory you can type `ls -la` to see a list of all the files and folders included the hidden ones that start with a "." You can open the files using the `open` command followed by the file name. You can also go inside the hidden directory by using the same `cd` command from before followed by the directory name.

Comment: Is there also a terminal workaround for this problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410076/150109 ?

Comment: @theonlygusti I posted an answer there as well.