# How to open/upload hidden files in apps or webapps?

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, filesystem

I can't view `.DS_Store`, `.localized`, `._.*` and `._*` with Finder: [Show ALL files starting with a dot in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410071/150109)

user3439894 commented there that it's impossible to do so with Finder:

> Some *dot files*, e.g. `.DS_Store`, you can see in **Terminal** using e.g. `ls -a` however the ones you used to see in **Finder** and cannot now see them is because **Finder** is programmed to not show those files files even with it's set to show *hidden files*. The `._*` and `._.*` are *extended attributes/resource fork files* and normally cannot be seen in **Terminal** or **Finder** when properly associated/linked to their *normal files* or if created on a *filesystem* which does support them and either viewed from **Finder** or brought back to an **HFS+**/**APFS** *filesystem*.

And an answer on SO [Unable to show .DS_Store file on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54937530/3310334) also says it's impossible with Finder.

So my question is, how can I send my handwritten file `._.` to people on Discord?

I can't drag-and-drop the file to Discord, because I can't see it in Finder in the first place, and also the upload dialogue uses macOS' Finder file browser as most apps do so I also can't select the file manually after clicking the "Browse..." button.

Comment: If you archive (compress) the _file(s)_, the e.g. **.zip** archive should include the _extended attributes/resource fork files_, so pass the **.zip** archive off instead. Note however if the destination _filesystem_ is not **HFS+/APFS** then those files will become unlinked and meaningless.

Comment: @user3439894 I just manually created a file called `._.` and want to send it on discord

Comment: Why are you creating a file named `._.`? As I said, archive it, e.g. `zip dot_dot ._.` and send the `dot_dot.zip` _file_.

Comment: @user3439894 it's an emoticon, just part of having fun with messaging friends online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question, I can tell you that it is possible for you to create a file name "._." and then share it however, discord will automatically change the filename when you upload. This is how you do it tough. First, open the terminal then type the command `touch ._.` then type `open ._.` this will open the file in the text editor. Once you have the file opened type whatever you want in there, once you are done, open discord, and then drag the blank file icon from your text editor into discord. However, as I said, there is no point because discord will change the file name.