# How to show all hidden files in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

How can I permanently compel the Finder to show me hidden files?

Previously I've done this by configuring the Mac OS X user defaults system as suggested [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5871/179974):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true
killall Finder
```

However that command does not work on Monterey. Adding a screenshot below of what I've tried.

[image: A screenshot showing hidden files in Desktop revealed in Terminal, which are not shown in the Finder Desktop]

Comment: It's not that the command doesn't work (though it's long been replaced by the much simpler Cmd/Shift/. [full stop/period]) it's that even with hidden files showing, it will **still** hide some files, .DS_Store etc.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the question you have linked to. Have your read all the answers posted at the linked question?

Comment: Ah thank you @Tetsujin - it seems .DS_Store and .localized are files that aren't shown even with "com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles" set to true.

Comment: @David Anderson I did read the other answers linked in the post and none of the solutions there solved my problem because I was looking at .localized and .DS_Store. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: EricAndrewLewis: Which version of macOS (OS X) were you previously using where  `.localized` and `.DS_Store` appeared on your Desktop after using the answer given in your question?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I believe .DS_Store would display in a previous version of macOS. I’m not sure which, I would guess Catalina but this is anecdotal experience. I am unfamiliar with .localized and don’t remember seeing it previously.

Comment: On my 2013 iMac, Catalina does not show `.DS_Store`, `.localized` and any files starting with `._`. Anyway, it is interesting the some files are omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command referred to does generally work, except for some particular files which I was attempting to look at including `.DS_Store` and `.localized`.

Comment: Sure, accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The desktop is not the dock is not the finder. So the same one file can exist in all three places visually and be shown differently.

You would need to open a finder window and navigate to the desktop folder to see the finder view of the contents of that directory. Both .localized and .DS_Store are specialized files which serve as hidden metadata which will affect how files other than themselves are presented. Most normal document files should be easy to manage as hidden or not but those are special cases.

Comment: I think the Desktop may be part of the Finder. It seems the setting "com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles" and pressing Command+Shift+. both affect the Desktop view and a Finder window.

Thanks for the note about .localized and .DS_Store being special cases here.

Comment: @EricAndrewLewis: I do not think the Desktop is part of the Finder. You can enter the command `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to quit'` and the Desktop will still be there without the file icons and names.

Answer (score 1):

In any Finder window, press Command+Shift+. This will toggle the show all files (including hidden ones).

Comment: Evidently, not necessarily all files.

Answer (score 0):

You very reasonably ask "How can I permanently compel the Finder to show me hidden files?". The short answer is you can't! Finder has changed.

With Big Sur and even more with Monterey, Finder no longer shows the file system unadulterated. Even with `Command+shift+.`, Finder does not show the full file system.

Three examples:

- The Documents folder as shown by Finder may have extra folders when hidden files are shown. Mine includes a hidden folder called BBEdit which in the file system is `~/Library/Containers/com.barebones.bbedit/Data/Documents`. This example is not present in `ls -a ~/Documents`
- When Finder shows the Applications folder it is combining two locations in the underlying file system, that is `/Applications` and `/System/Applications`. For example you won't find Mail in `ls -a /Applications`.
- Finder hides some files (even with show hidden files).  As you have found this includes `.DS_Store` which is always hidden.

There are various ways to see the true file system:

- The `Terminal` app and the `ls -a` command shows the file system.
- Use [ForkLift](https://binarynights.com) from binarynights or other 3rd party Finder replacements. ForkLift is much closer to the true file system. It shows `.DS_Store`, and doesn't show pretend Documents folders. But it does show the combined view for the Applications folder.

I presented this as Finder lying about the file system. The alternative view is that Finder shows you what you need to know. Those who want (or even need) to see more will know how to do so!

Note: In the above I have deliberately referred to Documents and Applications (and not `~/Documents` and `/Applications`) where I am referring to the pseudo-locations presented by Finder.